# How do I take the difference of two datetime columns in power bi?

Tags: datetime, datatable, powerbi, multiple-columns

I have two different datetime columns in two different tables T1 and T2. I have defined a one-to-one relationship between the two tables using a common column named 'id'. I want to make a new column that stores the difference of the datetime columns, for which I used the following command:

```
date3= DATEDIFF('T1'[date1], 'T2'[date2],DAY)
```

This command is not working and the message says, "A single value of date2 cannot be determined in the table T2".

The dates are in the following format: 10-12-2019 12:00:00.
How do I take the difference?

Comment: Read: Related() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax

Answer (score 1):

Add a *Calculated Column* to T1:

```
date3 = DATEDIFF('T1'[date1], RELATED('T2'[date2]), DAY)
```